# Django OneToOneField deleting child doesn't set parents parameter as None?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models in my Django app

```
class Product(models.ModelField):
  name = ...

class Discount(models.ModelField):
  product_id = models.OneToOneField(Product)
```

Basically, each product can have an optional discount.Now, assume I have only one product `p` with discount `d` attached. I want to delete the discount associated with the product p. So, I use

```
p.discount.delete()
```

While this makes `Discount.objects.all()` return `[]`, `p.discount` still the associated discount object.

How do I set this attribute to `None`?

Comment: If one `Product` object will have only one `Discount` object, why don't you set `discount` field in `Product` as `null=True, blank=true` and set `p.discount = None`?

Comment: Yeah. I tried that. I got confused because delete the actual model didn't remove the discount from the product. Somehow, the memory thing didn't occur to me. Just wanted to know the reason for what was happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p.discount = None
```

Changing something in the database will *not* affect model instances in memory.  In 1.8 you can also easily reload the object from the db:

```
p.refresh_from_db()
```

Or before 1.8:

```
p = Product.objects.get(pk=p.pk)
```